# proper way of creating method in your custom listview adapter

Tags: java, android

I created a simple android application with a `ListView` in it. I have my custom list adapter below:

```
package com.example.android.efaas;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.android.R;
import com.example.android.efaas.bean.ListItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    Context ctx;
    List<ListItem> data;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<ListItem> data){
        ctx = activity;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup vgroup) {
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, null);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_menu_image);
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_menu_title);

        ListItem item = data.get(pos);
        img.setImageResource(item.getId());
        title.setText(item.getTitle());

        return rowView;
    }

    public ListItem getListItem(int pos){
        return data.get(pos);
    }

}
```

I have a public method `getListItem`, I tried to call it during `ListView` onClick but somehow I cant seem to make it work. Here's the image of the problem:
[image]

**How do I resolve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should cast `adapter.getAdapter()` to `CustomListAdapter` class then

Comment: I tried this one `CustomListAdapter a = (CustomListAdapter) adapter;` but it didn't worked!

Comment: An `AdapterView` is not an `Adapter`. You'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 2):

the compile time error is due of the fact that `adapter` is not  your `CustomListAdapter`. What you can do is cast the return value of `adapter.getAdapter()` to `CustomListAdapter`. Conversely you should use what's already available to retrieve the object at position. Like [getItemAtPosition(int)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition(int))